# Custom tooltip with google chart and Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, google-visualization

I´m trying to create customs tooltips with google charts and Laravel.

```
    var rdb = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['', 'Contract Cost', 'Deployment Cost', {label: 'T2', role: 'tooltip'}],
    @foreach($rdbs as $rdb)
        @foreach ($rdb as $result)         
        ['{{mb_strimwidth($result->product, 0,50,"...")}}', {{$result->contract_costs}},{{$result->deployment_costs}},'{{$result->product}}'],
        @endforeach   
    @endforeach
```

The '' has a product name limit to 50, the tooltips that I need to show have full product name. ¿Any idea why this code doesn't work? The tooltips show name with limit to 50, not with the full name.

**Update:**

```
var full= $( "panel-body" ).width();

    var options = {
        width: full,
        height: rdb.getNumberOfRows()*20,
        bars: 'horizontal', 
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when using custom tooltips,
the tooltip role needs to follow the series column it represents
each y-axis series should have its own tooltip column

you have *two* y-axis series (`'Contract Cost'` & `'Deployment Cost'`)
but only *one* tooltip column

to correct and show the full name for both tooltips,
add another tooltip column after `'Contract Cost'`

```
var rdb = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
['', 'Contract Cost', {label: 'T1', role: 'tooltip'}, 'Deployment Cost', {label: 'T2', role: 'tooltip'}],
@foreach($rdbs as $rdb)
    @foreach ($rdb as $result)         
    ['{{mb_strimwidth($result->product, 0,50,"...")}}',{{$result->contract_costs}},'{{$result->product}}',{{$result->deployment_costs}},'{{$result->product}}'],
    @endforeach   
@endforeach
```

---

**EDIT**

[column roles](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles), such as `'tooltip'`, **are not supported** by *Material* charts...

see --> [Tracking Issue for Material Chart Feature Parity](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2143)
for the several other options that are not supported...

*Material* --> `google.charts.Bar` -- `packages: ['bar']`

*Classic* --> `google.visualization.BarChart` -- `packages: ['corechart']`

note: there is an option to style *Classic* charts **similar** to *Material* charts

```
theme: 'material'
```

Comment: Mm, doesn´t work. The chart tooltips display {{mb_strimwidth($result->product, 0,50,"...")}} name, limit 50, not full name.